# Toggle active class on button click

Tags: jquery

In this code where new sets of `.options` are created with every click of `.clone`, I want to be able to add the `focus` class to only the clicked `button` of each item and subsequently remove the `focus` class of all non-clicked buttons. I'm stuck at removing the `focus` class to all not-clicked buttons.

Note that the HTML and Jquery markup needs to remain the same given that it is a compenent of a larger function at site.

```js
var uniqueId = 1;
$(function() {
  $(".btn--new").click(function() {
    var copy = $("#s_item").clone(true, true);
    var formId = "item_" + uniqueId;
    copy.attr("id", formId);
    $("#s_list").append(copy);
    $("#" + formId)
      .find(".options")
      .each(function() {
        var list = $(this);
        $("[data-type='studio']").click(function() {
          list.find(this).removeClass("focus");
          $(this).addClass("focus");
        });

        var $catoptions = $(this).find(".button"),
          catrandom = ~~(Math.random() * $catoptions.length);
        $catoptions.eq(catrandom).click();
      });
    uniqueId++;
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn--new").trigger("click");
  $(".btn--new").trigger("click");
  $(".btn--new").trigger("click");
});
```

```css
#s_item {
  display: none;
}

.options {
  display: flex;
}

.focus {
  color: green;
  font-weight: 900
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn--new">Clone</button>
<div id="s_list">
  <div class="post__item studio__item" action="" id="s_item">
    <div class="options">
      <button type="button" class="button" data-type="studio">Dog</button>
      <button type="button" class="button" data-type="studio">Cat</button>
      <button type="button" class="button" data-type="studio">Bird</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

## Updated demo: https://jsfiddle.net/nd1owcmk/

Without changing any of your code, just add one set of script, that will take out the un-click button's focus class.

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("focus").siblings().removeClass('focus');
});
```

## JQuery

```
var uniqueId = 1;
$(function() {
  $(".btn--new").click(function() {
    var copy = $("#s_item").clone(true, true);
    var formId = "item_" + uniqueId;
    copy.attr("id", formId);
    $("#s_list").append(copy);
    $("#" + formId)
      .find(".options")
      .each(function() {
        var list = $(this);
        $("[data-type='studio']").click(function() {
          list.find(this).removeClass("focus");
          $(this).addClass("focus");
        });

        var $catoptions = $(this).find(".button"),
          catrandom = ~~(Math.random() * $catoptions.length);
        $catoptions.eq(catrandom).click();
      });
        uniqueId++;
  }); 

  $(".button").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("focus").siblings().removeClass('focus');
  });

});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn--new").trigger("click");
  $(".btn--new").trigger("click");
  $(".btn--new").trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: @ yeyene the button focus should apply to each set of buttons under `.options`. So each will have the focus applied to one of the buttons through the random function, and then have it removed when any of the other buttons are clicked in that same list

Comment: Oh, i wasn't clear what you wanted. Just updated the answer to meet your requirement, pls check again.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you simply need to call `removeClass('focus')` to remove it from all previous elements when you set the class on the latest clicked element.

Also note that you can simplify and DRY up your code by using common classes instead of runtime-generated `id` attributes (which is generally considered an anti-pattern) and also by using delegated event handlers. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  let $list = $('#list');
  
  $(".clone").click(function() {
    let $clone = $('.item:first').clone();
    $clone.find('.focus').removeClass('focus red blue');
    $clone.appendTo($list);
  });
  
  $list.on('click', '.options button', function() {
    $('.focus').removeClass('focus red blue');
    var $button = $(this);
    $button.addClass('focus ' + $button.data('color'));
  });
});
```

```css
#s_item { display: none; }
.category__list { display: flex; }
.focus { color: white; }
.blue { background-color: blue; }
.red { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="clone">Clone</button>

<div id="list">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="options">
      <div class="category__item">
        <div class="input--studio">
          <button type="button" class="button" value="blue" data-filter="blue" data-rel="blue" data-type="item" data-color="blue">Blue</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="category__item">
        <div class="input--studio">
          <button type="button" class="button" value="red" data-filter="red" data-rel="red" data-type="item" data-color="red">Red</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that the code is a snippet from a bigger and more embedded function and that the markup should remain the same given the structure at site.

Answer (score 0):

In the `document.ready` function I have to get the count of the trigger item then I have stored it in a `localstorage`. Using that `localstorage` item with the if condition I have removed the focus.

I hope this will helps you.

```js
var uniqueId = 1;
$(function() {
  $(".btn--new").click(function() {
    var copy = $("#s_item").clone(true, true);
    var formId = "item_" + uniqueId;
    copy.attr("id", formId);
    $("#s_list").append(copy);

    $("#" + formId)
      .find(".options")
      .each(function() {
        var list = $(this);
        $("[data-type='studio']").click(function() {
          list.find(this).removeClass("focus");
          $(this).addClass("focus");
        });

        var $catoptions = $(this).find(".button"),
          catrandom = ~~(Math.random() * $catoptions.length);
        $catoptions.eq(catrandom).click();
      });
    if (uniqueId > 3) {
      //localStorage.getItem("triggered")
      $("#" + formId + ' .button').removeClass('focus');
    }
    uniqueId++;
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn--new").trigger("click");
  $(".btn--new").trigger("click");
  $(".btn--new").trigger("click");
  //localStorage.setItem("triggered", ($('#s_list .post__item ').length) - 1);
});
```

```css
#s_item {
  display: none;
}

.options {
  display: flex;
}

.focus {
  color: green;
  font-weight: 900
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn--new" data-clone='true'>Clone</button>
<div id="s_list">
  <div class="post__item studio__item" action="" id="s_item">
    <div class="options">
      <button type="button" class="button" data-type="studio">Dog</button>
      <button type="button" class="button" data-type="studio">Cat</button>
      <button type="button" class="button" data-type="studio">Bird</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```